# Pulling key value from array in Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to pull specific key values from an array that is returned after using the requests library to perform a GET request. Here is a sample of what is returned from the GET request:

```
{
  'response': {
     'members': [
        {
         'id': 5562221,
         'pacing': False,
         'file_name': None,
         'id': 5562227,
         'pacing': False,
         'file_name': None,
         }]
```

This is what my code looks like. I am trying to pull all of the 'id' key values:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

member_advert_list = json.loads(response.text)

final_member_list = member_advert_list["response"]["members"]["id]

print final_member_list
```

After running my code, I receive a "string indices must be integers, not str" error. Am I going about this the wrong way? Do I need to also run a loop to pull these "Id" key values? I saw a similar question on here about this error message in python but my situation is a bit different being that I am trying to pull data returned in JSON format from a GET request. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't understand why you have `members` on your data structure and `creatives` on your code.

Comment: Copy and paste mistake, which I corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code would give a list of all of the IDs.

```
import json
string = '{"response":{"members":[{"id": 123}, {"id": 456}]}}' # simplified data structure
data = json.loads(string)
ids = map(lambda x: x['id'], data['response']['members'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you explain what "a" is supposed to do here? Was this just supposed to be a placeholder for something?

Comment: @user7681184 sorry, it was a variable typo.